# Why and how do I fix this website navigation error (caused by ie.document not updating?)

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I have been trying to log in and scrape data from a website to put it in an excel database. I have no trouble getting the data once I have the correct ie.document of it, however getting there is proving to be challenging.

This website requires me to sign in, then input the correct date for my search, then provides me with the data I need. I am having no trouble signing in - but I am having trouble changing the input value of the date that I need on the search screen URL.

I have attempted to find the error by looking at the number of inputs the login screen has, and comparing it to the number of inputs the search screen has. When looking at it manually, the login screen has 3 input elements, and the search screen has 290.
The code is as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Sub loginEIM(username As String, password As String, ie As Object)
    ie.document.GetElementsByName("UserName")(0).Value = username
    ie.document.GetElementsByName("UserPswd")(0).Value = password
    ie.document.GetElementsByName("LogonButton")(0).Click

    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 5, Now)
End Sub

Sub accessEIM()
    Dim username As String
    Dim password As String
    Dim itemType As String
    Dim dateWanted As Date

    itemType = "SU"
    username = "myusername"
    password = "mypassword"
    dateWanted = "31/05/2018"

'I am planning on setting itemtype, username, password and date wanted as 
variables in accessEIM()
'I have declared them here for testing purposes however...

    If itemType = "SU" Then
        Call signedUp(dateWanted, username, password)
    ElseIf itemType = "Can" Then
        'Call Cancelled
   ElseIf itemType = "Clo" Then
        'Call Closed
    End If
End Sub

Sub signedUp(dateWanted As Date, username As String, password As String)
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim URL As String
    Dim dayWanted As String
    Dim monthWanted As String
    Dim yearWanted As String

    dayWanted = Day(dateWanted)
    monthWanted = Month(dateWanted)
    yearWanted = Year(dateWanted)
    URL = "myurl"
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 2880
        .Height = 1080
        .Width = 960
    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    End With

    If ie.document.GetElementsByTagName("INPUT").Length = 3 Then
        Call loginEIM(username, password, ie)
    Else
    End If
    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

'The error occurs here - ie.document seems to still be the same as in the 
login screen
'I know this because ie.document.GetElementsByTagName("INPUT").Length still 
= 3, it should be a lot more than that.
'I have tried closing and re-opening a new ie object, and navigating to 
that, as the website no longer asks me to login again,
'but I encountered errors when the first instance wasn't closing with 
ie.quit
'I have tried set ie = Nothing, but I get an error with that also.
'I tried adding a 5 second timer, and then sometimes it gets caught up on 
the ie.busy loop above,
'Sometimes it runs through and just gets stuck on Name("DD31")(0).

    ie.document.GetElementsByName("DD31")(0).Value = ""
    ie.document.GetElementsByName("MM31")(0).Value = ""
    ie.document.GetElementsByName("YY31")(0).Value = ""
    'ie.document.GetElementsByName("Search")(0).Click
End Sub
```

I would greatly appreciate help in either refreshing the ie.document or finding a workaround, or pointing out any glaring errors.

Apologies for not including the URL or HTML code, but I don' think that is where the problem stems from in this instance, and I would need to get permission to post them.

(I have tried ie.refresh, and ie.refresh2(1), but that doesn't seem to work either)

Thanks for your time!

Tytrox

Comment: Could you provide the link on which you like to achieve this?

Comment: @Luuklag I am sorry, no - I don't yet have permission to share that, and I'm not sure a login screen would help too much with this. I am almost certain that the issue here isn't to do with the html. The input elements are all uniquely named, and if I bypass the login screen, the  search for ie.doccument.GetElementsByName("DD31")(0).Value = "hello" works fine.

Comment: Is your search string represented into the resulting URL?

Comment: @Luuklag No, it isn't. I tried to close the login screen after I clicked the logonbutton and open a new instance of internet explorer where I checked if ie.doccument.GetElementsByTagName("INPUT").Length = 290, which did work (and input into the ("DD31")). However I then got an issue where the fist instance of internetexplorer didn't close with ie.quit, but the second one did. When I then tried to load the url of the resulting search directily with .navigate in a third instance of internetexplorer, I was logged out again.

Comment: @Luuklag Surely there is a way to update the ie.document to the search screen so I don't need to keep encountering errors with multiple instances of internet explorer? By the way, thank you for helping :)

Comment: perhaps try with selenium basic?

Comment: @QHarr, Thanks, I'll give it a go, I'd never heard of selenium before :)

Comment: @Tytrox http://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/

Comment: Have you tried stepping through code with F8? Why do you need to check whether you are on search screen through counting of number of elements, when `ie.Visible = True`? "The error appears here" - do you mean on `ie.document.GetElementsByName("DD31")(0).Value = ""` line? It's not very clear for me. Instead of stepping through code and waiting for some time, you can also add 10 second wait before 1st line on newly loaded `ie.document` and see what happens. Maybe there is JavaScript being processed which `ie.Busy` and `ie.readyState = 4` don't handle.

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk Thank you, I didn't know you could step through the code with F8. The reason I counted elements of the search screen to check if I was on it was due to the website doesn't always pop up the search screen first - hence when the code looks for the "UserName" element it throws up an error when it can't find it - hence the login screen check via counting input elements.

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk As for "the error occurs here" - apologies for not being specific. Yes, it occurs on the ie,document.GetElementsByName("DD31")(0).Value = "" , object not found when the login screen loads first, but when the search screen loads first no error occurs. That's what lead me to think that ie.document wasn't updating, so I put a msgbox(ie.document.GetElementsByName("INPUT").Length) before the ("DD31") line to check - when the login screen loads first, this count is still 3, when the .navigate line takes me straight to the search, the count is 290.

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk Thank you for your help, I will try the F8 method and the 10 second wait.

Comment: @QHarr Thanks, I am now using chrome for this with selenium basic, it's working well, and is much more simple to use, thank you!

Comment: Good to hear. I like it.